# Loading revisions changes svn:author

Tags: svn

When attempting to svnrdump load {PATH TO REPO} < {PATH TO DUMP} as the revisions are being loaded it will change the author of each revision to be my user. I am loading from a windows machine up to a Linux server that is why rdump used

I am not using any hooks apart from the default pre-revprop-change hook which I am exiting with code 0 immediately although I have now changed this back to the default one to save me having to remake the repository every time

Current Pre rev propchange hook

```
REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"
USER="$3"
PROPNAME="$4"
ACTION="$5"

if [ "$ACTION" = "M" -a "$PROPNAME" = "svn:log" ]; then exit 0; fi

echo "Changing revision properties other than svn:log is prohibited" >&2
exit 1
```

I am wanting to keep the original author of the commits the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I seem to be able to get around this issue is to load the dump file from the actual linux server using the svnadmin commands and not doing it remotely believe this has something to do with how we have out authentication set up